# Can you enable [Authorize] for controller but disable it for a single action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I would like to use `[Authorize]` for every action in my admin controller except the `Login` action.

```
[Authorize (Roles = "Administrator")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    // what can I place here to disable authorize?
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with the standard Authorize attribute, but you could derive your own attribute from AuthorizeAttribute that takes a list of actions to allow and allows access to just those actions.  You can look at the source for the AuthorizeAttribute at [www.codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet) for ideas on how to do this.  If you did, it might look like:

```
[AdminAuthorize (Roles = "Administrator", Exempt = "Login, Logout") ]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    ... other, restricted actions ...
}
```

**EDIT**:  FYI, I eventually ran across a need to do something similar on my own and I went a different direction.  I created a default authorization filter provider and apply a global authorize filter.  The authorization filter provider uses reflection to check if an action or controller has a specific authorize attribute applied and, if so, defers to it.  Otherwise, it applies a default authorization filter.  This is coupled with a PublicAttribute derived from AuthorizeAttribute that allows public access.  Now, I get default secured access, but can grant public access via `[Public]` applied to an action or controller.  More specific authorization can also be applied as necessary.  See my blog at http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.com/2011/04/default-authorization-filter-provider.html

Comment: Looks like you're correct according to http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/SourceControl/changeset/view/17272 I'm guessing the attribute gets applied at the controller level and never gives the action an attempt to evaluate it.

Comment: Hmm apparently you can't link directly to the source file on codeplex.

Answer (score 29):

You can decorate your controller with [Authorize] and then you can just decorate the method that you want to exempt with [AllowAnonymous]

Comment: Isn't this the correct answer?  Or perhaps this was not the case in 2008 when the question was asked...

Comment: Which framework are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 5):

You could override the OnAuthorization method of the controller

```
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if ((string)(filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]) == "Login")
        {
            filterContext.Cancel = true;
            filterContext.Result = Login();
        }
    }
```

This works but it is a hack.

Full class code used for testing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{
[HandleError]
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "About Page";

        return View();
    }


    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if ((string)(filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]) == "Index")
        {
            filterContext.Cancel = true;
            filterContext.Result = Index();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does this get called before or after the [Authorize] attribute?

Comment: It looks like the [Authoirze] attribute is evaluated first and never gets to the OnAuthoirization method.

Comment: Gets called every time for me.

Comment: Looking again at your question, you should be able to use the line fliterContext.Result = View("Login"); as well

Comment: OnAuthorization is getting called except when I have a [Authorize] attribute on the controller itself.

Comment: Are you using the beta of the MVC or one of the previews? I have the [Authorize] attribute on the controller as well.

Comment: I'm using the beta. Perhaps the difference is the roles [Authorize (Roles = "Administrator")]

Comment: glad to know I am not crazy :)

Comment: There is one catch with this approach, if you have two versions of your login, one for get and one for post and your methods are decorated with [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)] and [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] then the OnAuthorization method gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: only a little, use filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod for the verb

Comment: Note, that `Cancel` property of `AuthorizationContext` has been removed since RC1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505653/what-happened-to-filtercontext-cancel-asp-net-mvc/505679#505679

Answer (score 1):

May be it's not actual, but I wrote my custom attribute:

```
public class SelectableAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public SelectableAuthorizeAttribute(params Type[] typesToExclude)
    {
        _typesToExlude = typesToExclude;
    }

    private readonly Type[] _typesToExlude;

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool skipAuthorization = _typesToExlude.Any(type => filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType == type);

        if (!skipAuthorization)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And then registered it in my global filetrs:

```
filters.Add(new SelectableAuthorizeAttribute(typeof(MyController)));
```

Hope that it will be useful for someone