# What happened to filterContext.Cancel (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

Before RC1 we did something like this:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (whatever)
        {
            filterContext.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

This is gone now, how do we achieve the same results with RC1?

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of a `Cancel` property you just need to set the `ActionResult` to a different result. So for the `Cancel` property, you just have to replace your `Cancel=true` with

```
filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

[REFERENCE](http://forums.asp.net/p/1376982/2898597.aspx#2898597)

Breaking Changes for RC1:

`AuthorizationContext` - no longer has a `Cancel` property

`UpdateModel` - no longer accepts a `FormCollection`

`UrlHelper` - no longer accepts a `ViewContext`

[Scotts Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/01/27/asp-net-mvc-1-0-release-candidate-now-available.aspx) with the [White Papers](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=137661&clcid=0x409) of RC1 changes.