# ASP .NET MVC Secure all resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

How to enable Authentication on whole controller and disable only for certain action methods. I want authentication for all resources. If I write something like that:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    //This is public
    [UnAuthorized]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        return View();
    }
    //This is private resource
    public ActionResult PrivateResource()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then anyone can access this resource. I need this because we have all resources are private and very few are public on our project. Do you have any ideas how to make it better way?

Comment: Duplicate see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071235/overriding-controller-authorizeattribute-for-just-one-action and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537307/asp-net-mvc-can-i-say-authorize-rolesadministrators-on-the-controller-class

Comment: No. it's not the answer for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on solution which is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329500/can-you-enable-authorize-for-controller-but-disable-it-for-a-single-action/329562#329562) I wrote the code that fixes exactly what I wanted.

Create custom authorization attribute base on AuthorizeAttribute and override method OnAuthorization:

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext != null)
        {
            object[] attributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(false);
            if (attributes != null)
            {
                foreach (var attribute in attributes)
                    if (attribute is UnAuthorizedAttribute)
                        return;
            }
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
```

I'm using a reflection here to recognize an action with UnAuthorized attribute. I don't know about performance issues in this case, but it solves the problem completely.

Comment: Much of this code is unnecessary.  Just use ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes() directly, so you can bypass using reflection to guess what the incoming method is.

Answer (score 3):

Organize your controllers accordingly. Have a base controller for all authenticated resources which you could annotate with the `[Authorize]` attribute and another one for public resources.

```
[Authorize]
public abstract BaseAuthenticatedController : Controller
{ }

public abstract BaseController : Controller
{ }
```

Comment: Thank you Darin. It is not what I wanted exactly. I want to be able to make certain action methods of controller to be public and rest of them private.

Answer (score 0):

It's really strange that no one said about AllowAnonymous attribute which services for such situations:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    //This is public
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        return View();
    }
    //This is private resource
    public ActionResult PrivateResource()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```