# How to exclude one controller action from authorize filter in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC 3 I can put AuthorizeAttribute inside Global.asax's RegisterGlobalFilters, and it will apply to all controllers' actions. But how can I exclude some controller actions so these actions can be called without the user logging in?

EDIT:

Sorry, additional question, if I add authorize on the class, how can I exclude one action?

Comment: This guy describes exactly what your looking for with very little code and step by step explanation.. Introducing a `global Authorization Filter` and an `AllowAnonymousAttribute` http://blog.tomasjansson.com/2011/08/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application

Comment: [This post describe a way how to exclude arbitrary filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684150/a-way-to-exclude-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc) (see question, not answer). I am not aware of ASP.NET MVC 3 but it seems plausible.

Comment: Implemented my own custom filter. Please see my post here it it will be useful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11554471/188862

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this with global filters. As their name indicates => they are global.

One way is to have all controllers that require authorization derive from a common base controller decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute. Controllers that doesn't require authorization will not derive from this base controller.

Another possibility in ASP.NET MVC 3 is to write a custom [IFilterProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ifilterprovider.aspx) which based on the context will apply or not the given filters. I would recommend you reading the [following blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html).

Comment: Why not use reflection to check if the current action has another filter applied (say [DontAuthorize]) and in this case bypass the functionality in the filter? This should work fine...

Comment: @JP, do you have a sample?